# When subclassing RKObjectRequestOperation to check for errors, how to retry the failed operation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have subclassed RKManagedObjectRequestOperation and overriding the following method,

```
    - (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure
{

    [super setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (success) {
            success(operation, mappingResult);
        }

    }failure:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error) {

        NSInteger statusCode = operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode;
        switch (statusCode) {
            case  401: // not authenticated
            {
                MyError* errorResponse = (MyError*)[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey"] firstObject];
                if(errorResponse && [errorResponse.oauth2ErrorCode isEqualToString:@"invalid_token"]){

                    RKObjectRequestOperation* repeatOp = [operation copy];
                    [repeatOp setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InvalidTokenFailure" object:repeatOp];

                } else{

                    if (failure) {
                        failure(operation, error);
                    }

                }

            }
                break;

            default:
            {
                if (failure) {
                    failure(operation, error);
                }

            }
                break;
        }
    }];
}
```

Then in the observer of the failure notification, I issue a request to refresh the oauth token and on success, I want to enqueue the original request again, but after substituting the querystring parameter from the original operation.

In the code for the notification observer:

```
-(void)restRequestFailedWithOperation:(NSNotification*)notification{

    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *)notification.object;
    if (operation) {

                // issue token refresh request and in its success block:
                ..... 

                 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

         }      
}
```

I did not see a means to replace a specific querystring parameter within a RKManagedObjectRequestOperation. And since the original operation still has the old token, enqueueing it again will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to move the concern of appending oauth tokens to each outgoing request is to subclass the RKHTTPRequestOperation class and override the method

```
-(NSURLRequest*)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

}
```

This will ensure that each outgoing request will get the most current oauth token. It gets you away from needing to modify the failed operation with a new request.

Make sure to register the subclass(MyHTTPRequestOperation) like this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] registerRequestOperationClass:[MyHTTPRequestOperation class]];
```

I am not confident that this is the best approach. Ideally, the pattern set by RKPaginator class could be implemented. RKPaginator allows for easy repeat of same request while modifying some query parameters.